# What is similar in Rust to the colon operator in C?

Tags: rust

How to represent this kind of code in Rust?

```
uint8_t  pmport:4;  
uint8_t  rsv0:3;        
uint8_t  c:1;
```

I want to pack these 3 values into a single `u8`. How can this be achieved in Rust?

Comment: I'd highly recommend learning the proper name for the tools and techniques you are using. That's not an "operator" and it goes by the name [bit field](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust does not have bit fields built into the language like C does.
However, you can use a crate like [bitfield](https://crates.io/crates/bitfield) to achieve the same thing.
The `bitfield` macro lets you define the types, size and accessor methods for each bit field.

```
#[macro_use] extern crate bitfield;

bitfield! {
    struct Example(u8);
    u8;
    get_pmport, set_pmport: 3, 0; // bits 0-3
    get_rsv0, set_rsv0: 6, 4;     // bits 4-6
    get_c, set_c: 7, 7;           // bit 7
}

fn main() {
    println!("size of Example: {}", ::std::mem::size_of::<Example>());
    let mut e = Example(0);
    println!("pmport: {}, rsv0: {}, c: {}", e.get_pmport(), e.get_rsv0(), e.get_c());
    e.set_pmport(5);
    println!("pmport: {}, rsv0: {}, c: {}", e.get_pmport(), e.get_rsv0(), e.get_c());
    e.set_rsv0(3);
    println!("pmport: {}, rsv0: {}, c: {}", e.get_pmport(), e.get_rsv0(), e.get_c());
    e.set_c(1);
    println!("pmport: {}, rsv0: {}, c: {}", e.get_pmport(), e.get_rsv0(), e.get_c());
    e.set_rsv0(0);
    println!("pmport: {}, rsv0: {}, c: {}", e.get_pmport(), e.get_rsv0(), e.get_c());
}
```