# Is there a single bit type if not how to reprent gates logic that work only with bits as input and outpu

Tags: rust

Is there a single bit type in Rust?
Something equivalent to C: `unsigned x:1;`
The "1" represent the size, in this case one bit.

**Edit**

What should I do then if I want to do/represent the gates logic:
"And" gate two input(bit input) and one output bit
Same for the "Or" gate and so on...
Should I just ignore the size of the memory and work with u8?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467995/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-rust)

Comment: Related: [How does a C-style struct with a bitfield get represented in a Rust repr(C) struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45229167/how-does-a-c-style-struct-with-a-bitfield-get-represented-in-a-rust-reprc-s)

Comment: Nope, they work with a byte and flip on bit of that byte.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is similar in Rust to the colon operator in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349120/what-is-similar-in-rust-to-the-colon-operator-in-c)

Comment: In C, that syntax is only valid in a bitfield struct, and the type of `{struct}.x` is still just `unsigned int`, not a single-bit type.

Comment: C doesn't have this either don't confuse a bit type with a bitfield.

Comment: A bit type cannot exist in Rust (or most languages) because it would be impossible to take a reference to it (pointers are to bytes not bits), and there is no mechanism in Rust to enforce that a type cannot be referenced.

Comment: On the other hand, `#[repr(packed)]` structs *do* exist in Rust, and you may not reference their members either (although rustc does not forbid it, which is [the fourth-oldest outstanding I-unsound issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27060)). I think a greater concern is that bitfields (unlike packed structs) are not well supported or portable in C, so adding them to Rust would probably just add a bunch of new internal problems without really solving any FFI problems. You can always emulate them with shifts and masks, anyway (which is also what you do in C if you want portability).

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I updated my question.

Comment: What append to Stackoverflow asking me to delete my question even after editing... :(

Comment: The system should not ask you to delete your question. Questions closed as duplicates are not automatically deleted, but kept around to help future askers with similar questions find the same answers. If you can edit your question to make it on-topic and not a duplicate, it can be reopened ("what should I do" questions are not really on-topic, so I'm uncertain about the current state of the question), but there's nothing wrong with leaving it closed and not deleted.

Comment: To address your edited question, it's rather open-ended (which is why it's hard to make on-topic) but if you're not packing multiple bits into a byte there would seem to be no reason not to simply use `bool` (or a wrapper type around `bool`, or a custom `enum Bit { One, Zero }`). Any of those options would be the same size as `u8`, but also permit enum layout optimizations.

Comment: @trentcl Thanks for your help.

Comment: @trentcl There is no harm in referencing members of a `#[repr(packed)]` struct per se. The fields are still going to be aligned at least to a whole byte. The problem in the issue you linked is that a type is marked as requiring 128-bit alignment, but it's still possible to force it to break the alignment in safe code.